# is there any third party API to create custom text editor like word pad in an ipad or iphone

Tags: ipad

I need a text editor in my ipad app,to allow user to change the font,size etc. of entered text 
in an UITextField.Like we do in an word pad or other text editor.Please help me if any one has 
an idea about it.Thanks in advance.